# custom matchers how to load in jasmine-node?

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-node

I am using jasmine-node and want to reuse some custom matchers I have been using with karma. I cannot find how to load my custom matchers...

Using karma and jasmine 2.4 I can load them this way:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    jasmine.addMatchers(customMatchers);
});
```

But using jasmine-node it is not working.
I must be missing something because jasmine itself is actually undefined..Can some please guide me in the right direction? Thank-you